# can not read isJailBroken of undefined in react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

i am trying to check if the device is rooted in my react native application by using [jail-monkey repository](https://github.com/beast/react-native-isDeviceRooted#readme) like that:

i installed jail-monkey by this command: `npm install jail-monkey --save` and then i ran: `react-native link jail-monkey`

and in my codes where i want to check if the device is rooted:

```
import JailMonkey from ‘jail-monkey’


componentDidMount() {
    const isRooted = JailMonkey.isJailBroken(); // the application fails here
    console.log(isRooted)
}
```

it gives an error **can not read isJailBroken of undefined**.

Comment: Could you try `react-native link jail-monkey` not `react-native link`

Comment: i tried that, didn't work

Comment: The V~2.2.0 is working fine for Android but same error was coming on iOS so I fixed with pod install.

Comment: Still having same issue. 